# SQL Server Error Msg 5170 – How to I generate a new filename each time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm facing an issue where I'm getting error SQL Server error

> Msg 5170
> Cannot create file '%ls' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'example')
BEGIN
    CREATE DATABASE [example]
END
```

But I'm getting error "Msg 5170" saying it already exist when I look in the path `...\MSSQL\DATA` that `example.mdf` and `example_log.ldf` already exist. I'm trying to have it generate a new name every time like this `example123456` and `example1547886_log`.

How am I supposed to generate a new name if path file already exists? I've been looking all over the internet with no luck.

I tried using different file names for this database:

```
CREATE DATABASE _temp ON (NAME = '_temp',
   FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\_temp_of_20130404.mdf')
LOG ON (NAME = '_temp_log',
   FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\_temp_of_20130404.ldf')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure why you are doing this (instead of removing the old files if the database is no longer attached) but anyway.....

This will just generate new filenames base don the current date/time then build a sql statement up to create a new database. Obviously you can edit the sizes and/or paths as you wish.

```
DECLARE @dt varchar(14) = format(getdate(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss')

declare @dbf varchar(256) = CONCAT('c:\program files\microsoft sql server\mssql\data\exampledat', @dt, '.mdf')
declare @logf varchar(256) = CONCAT('c:\program files\microsoft sql server\mssql\data\examplelog', @dt, '.ldf')

declare @sql varchar(max) = CONCAT(

'CREATE DATABASE example
ON
( NAME = example_dat,
   FILENAME = ''', @dbf, ''',
   SIZE = 20MB,
   FILEGROWTH = 5MB )
LOG ON
( NAME = example_log,
   FILENAME = ''', @logf, ''',
   SIZE = 10MB,
   FILEGROWTH = 5MB )');

print @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: `QUOTENAME(@dbf, '''')` might be wise

Comment: Thank you I'm new to SQL Server and was facing this issue when I would remove server instance, but it wasn't removed from path. Alot of answers I found to fix the issue was either to change the filename but was hard coded or change the path but what if you did know where the path was.

Comment: I accepted the answer let me know if you see it on your end. I don't normally used stack overflow.

Comment: All good thanks (although it helps you just as much! ;) )